# Name a non-testing related activity that improved your testing?

Tags: qa-developer

I’m curious to know different activities that can help us as testers even that are not directly related to testing?

Answer (score 2):

### I think this is a really good question, a few things that helped me improve my testing skills are:

1. I developed a simple API using express to expose a database and access it through postman. It helped me in understanding what is an API actually and what am I actually testing when I say API testing. I also developed a simple API service for providing API automation training this helped me to explain what is an API other than the normal eg:

   "Imagine you are in a hotel and you order food , the waiter is the API :D"
2. I got involved in the business meeting which helped me to understand how the product makes money for the organization and what features were seen as flagship features that made the customers interested in the product. This helped me to test the application from a business perspective than just from functionality.

   I was able to provide design improve suggestions and feature recommendations
3. I take up an open project and provides fixes, this helps me understanding Whitebox content. Helps me in testing the product by keeping the code in mind than just the UI. This will allow in more focused attack points which I can break-in.
4. One such project was regarding HTML report for postman where I learned about HTML handlebars, template, and many more things about HTML which really made testing web a really easy task

Answer (score 1):

1. Reading
2. Thinking
3. Talking
4. Writing

about

- tech
- society
- history
- science
- people (society)
- anything else

Generally speaking, using scientific method on anything, i.e. trying to understand things and to create hypotesis that will confirm or disprove a theory about any one of the above-mentioned (but not limited to) categories.